# ROS Subscribe to multiple topics with single function

Tags: ros, callback, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for feedback and help in advance,

I want to give input of topic names, initial data and data_type as dictionary to a function, and that function will subscribe to each topic and save data to dictionary. This is what I have done so far.

**Example input**

```
ros_topics = {"rosTopic1": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type1"},
              "rosTopic2": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type2"},
              "rosTopic3": {"data": None,
                            "type": "msg_type3"}}
```

I can subscribe to multiple topics and show their output message, however I couldn't save them into dictionary.

**My function so far**

```
def subscribe_topics(self):
    for key in self.ros_topics.keys():
        rospy.Subscriber(name=key,
                         data_class=self.ros_topics[key]["type"],
                         callback=self.common_callback)

def common_callback(self, msg):
    print("####")
    # Want to store msg.data to ros_topics[key]["data"], however I couldn't transfer **key**
    print(msg)
    print("####")
```

[Stackoverflow Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74026635/ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-with-single-function)

- Python 3.8
- ROS Noetic
- Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407730/ros-subscribe-to-multiple-topics-with-single-function/) by [FurkanEdizkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/67078/furkanedizkan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2022-10-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shrini96](https://answers.ros.org/users/104316/shrini96/) on 2023-05-23**:
As someone fairly new to ROS, the `"msg_type1"` within double inverted commas sort of threw me off. So for anyone else stuck there, it is apparently not supposed to be a string containing the name of the type of message (for e.g. NOT `... {"rosTopic1": {"data": None, "type": "nav_msgs/Odometry"} ...`).

Rather, here is supposed to be the object itself, for eg `... {"rosTopic1": {"data": None, "type": Odometry} ...`

This is with the assumption that you have already added the required import line. For this case:
`from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry`

**Comment by [FurkanEdizkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/67078/furkanedizkan/) on 2023-07-14**:
Yes, you are correct, I write them in that way to just show any msg type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use `callback_args` parameter of the [Subscriber](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/rospy/html/rospy.topics.Subscriber-class.html) class.

In your case, you can set the `key` as shown below:

```
    rospy.Subscriber(name=key,
                     data_class=self.ros_topics[key]["type"],
                     callback=self.common_callback,
                     callback_args=key)
```

And then change the `callback` signature to accommodate key as shown below:

```
def common_callback(self, msg, args):
    key = args
```

I have not tested the above code. In case of an error, please inform and change the `callback_args` to a tuple.

For more information, please check [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/231492/passing-arguments-to-callback-in-python/?answer=231495#post-id-231495).

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-10-11**:
This question scratches the same itch: https://answers.ros.org/question/398554/dynamic-publishers-subscribers-and-callbacks/#398555

**Comment by [FurkanEdizkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/67078/furkanedizkan/) on 2022-10-12**:
Yes, it perfectly works. Thank you

**Comment by [FurkanEdizkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/67078/furkanedizkan/) on 2022-10-12**:
I can open an other question for this topic but since we are here, is this usage a good way to use ros subscriber?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-12**:
@FurkanEdizkan I am glad it worked. Yes, it is all right to use `callback_args`. If you face any problems with it, feel free to open a new question, as you said.

**Comment by [FurkanEdizkan](https://answers.ros.org/users/67078/furkanedizkan/) on 2022-10-12**:
Thank you for answer